# Unity spawning problems

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to have only 2 objects in the scene. When i call the method it spawns 2 objects no problem with that but when I destroy one of them and call the method again and it spawns another 2 so in my scene are 3 how to limit or check if there is already 2 objects so its spawns only one. Guys dont hate me with my code.
Spawn Manager

```
 public class SpawnMana : MonoBehaviour
 {  
     public GameObject stone;
     public GameObject water;
     public GameObject copper;
     public GameObject iron;
     public GameObject organism;
     public GameObject animals;
     public GameObject dinosaurs;
     public GameObject humans;
     public GameObject village;
     public GameObject castle;    
     
     public int numObjects = 0;
     
     public List<GameObject> objectsAdd;
 
     private MainMenu menu;

     void Start()
     {
         menu = GameObject.Find("MainMenu").GetComponent<MainMenu>();
         
         if (menu.a == true)
         {
             numObjects++;
             objectsAdd.Add(stone);
            
         }
 
         SpawnSpheres();       
 
     }
     Vector3 RandomCircle(Vector3 center, float radius, int a)
     {
         Debug.Log(a);
         float ang = Random.value * 360;
         Vector3 pos;
         pos.x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
         pos.y = center.y + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
         pos.z = center.z;
         return pos;
     }
     public void SpawnSpheres()
     {       
         int index = Random.Range(0, objectsAdd.Count);
         Vector3 center = transform.position;
         for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
         {
             int a = 360 / numObjects * i;
            Vector3 pos = RandomCircle(center, 7.0f, a);
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, center - pos);
            Instantiate(objectsAdd[index], pos, rot);
         }       
  
     }
     public void Water()
     {        
         numObjects++;
         objectsAdd.Add(water);       
     } 
     
 }
```

DetectCollisions

```
public class DetectCollisions : MonoBehaviour
```

{
private float xRange = 45;

```
 private float yRange = 20;

 private SpawnMana spawnMana;

 private GameManager gameMana;
 
 void Start()
 {

     spawnMana = GameObject.Find("SpawnMana").GetComponent<SpawnMana>();

     gameMana = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();

 }
  
 void Update()
 {
     if (transform.position.x > xRange)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
     if (transform.position.x < -xRange)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
     if (transform.position.y > yRange)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
     if (transform.position.y < -yRange)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
 }
 private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
     if (!CompareTag("BB"))          
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);            
     }
     if (CompareTag("Stone"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(1 , 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Water"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Copper"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Iron"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Organism"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0, 0, 0, 0, 1,0,0,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Animals"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1, 0,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Dinosaurs"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Humans"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Village"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,1,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Castle"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,1);
     }


 }
```

}

Comment: I am a bit confused about your code ... you have a loop iterating over `numObjects` and you have a line increasing that value `numObjects++;` .. so I would expect the longer your app goes he more items you spawn ... And instead of the tags and really uncanny `UpdateScore` method I would rather have a dedicated component on the prefabs and an `enum` for the mana type

Comment: and why do your mana's handle their own collisions? I would rather have a central controller on the player object and go the other way round .. the player checks what it collides with and forwards it to the also central other mangers ... And I would prefer lists instead of having a field for each prefab

Comment: Surely you count how many there are now. And spawn however many you need to make full set.

Comment: @derHugo Hello and thank you for your comment, so look this is game where you are planet creator before you create good planet you must collect resources, then you buy some upgrades. And my problem is when I add another numObjects++; it start spawning more and more on destroy and I dont know how to fix it. Watch the video  https://youtu.be/aHPlpD-kbDg

Comment: well as said .. you are increasing `numObjects` => ever time `SpawnSpheres` spawns one item more

Comment: @derHugo okay and do you have any tips how to fix it

Comment: Not increase the value .. or not use that field for the loop but use a separate one with fixed value ?

Answer (score 0):

SpawnMana:

```
public class SpawnMana : MonoBehaviour
 {  
     public GameObject stone;
     public GameObject water;
     public GameObject copper;
     public GameObject iron;
     public GameObject organism;
     public GameObject animals;
     public GameObject dinosaurs;
     public GameObject humans;
     public GameObject village;
     public GameObject castle;    
     
     public int numObjects = 0;
     public int currentObjects = 0;

     public static SpawnMana Instance = null;
     
     public List<GameObject> objectsAdd;
 
     private MainMenu menu;

     void Start()
     {
         Instance = this;
         menu = GameObject.Find("MainMenu").GetComponent<MainMenu>();
         
         if (menu.a == true)
         {
             numObjects++;
             objectsAdd.Add(stone);
            
         }
 
         SpawnSpheres();       
 
     }
     Vector3 RandomCircle(Vector3 center, float radius, int a)
     {
         Debug.Log(a);
         float ang = Random.value * 360;
         Vector3 pos;
         pos.x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
         pos.y = center.y + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
         pos.z = center.z;
         return pos;
     }
     public void SpawnSpheres()
     {       
         int index = Random.Range(0, objectsAdd.Count);
         Vector3 center = transform.position;
         for (int i = currentObjects; i < 2; i++)
         {
            currentObjects++;
             int a = 360 / numObjects * i;
            Vector3 pos = RandomCircle(center, 7.0f, a);
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, center - pos);
            Instantiate(objectsAdd[index], pos, rot);
         }       
  
     }
     public void Water()
     {        
         numObjects++;
         objectsAdd.Add(water);       
     } 
     
 }
```

DetectCollisions:

```
public class DetectCollisions : MonoBehaviour
{
 private float xRange = 45;

 private float yRange = 20;

 private SpawnMana spawnMana;

 private GameManager gameMana;
 
 void Start()
 {

     spawnMana = GameObject.Find("SpawnMana").GetComponent<SpawnMana>();

     gameMana = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();

 }
  
 void Update()
 {
     if (transform.position.x > xRange ||
         transform.position.x < -xRange || 
         transform.position.y > yRange ||
         transform.position.y < -yRange)
     {
         SpawnMana.Instance.currentObjects--;
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
 }
 private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
     if (!CompareTag("BB"))          
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);            
     }
     if (CompareTag("Stone"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(1 , 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Water"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Copper"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Iron"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Organism"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0, 0, 0, 0, 1,0,0,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Animals"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1, 0,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Dinosaurs"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,0,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Humans"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1,0,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Village"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,1,0);
     }
     if (CompareTag("Castle"))
     {
         spawnMana.SpawnSpheres();
         gameMana.UpdateScore(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,1);
     }


 }
}
```